# Mapping values from sensor in inverse

Tags: javascript, html, dom, sensors

Hi I am having great difficulty with this.

I have a sensor that is outputting values from it's z variable which I am capturing with an event listener - event.z increments from 20 to 100.

```
document.getElementById("size").style.width = event.z + "px";
```

When this is tied with the .width property of my element it increases the width proportionally of the element. This works great.
However I would like it to do the opposite, decrease the width while the values of the sensor are incrementing.
How can I "invert" the values of the sensor to make the width property decrease?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("size").style.width = 100 + (20 - event.z) + "px";
```

When your event.z says 20, this will give a width of 100px.
When your event.z says 100, this will give a width of 20px.

A general function for this kind of calculation is

```
function progress(start, finish, current) {
    if (start == finish) { return start; }

    var operator = 1;
    var min = start;
    if (start > finish) {
        operator = -1;
        min = finish;
    }

    return start + (Math.abs(current - min) * operator);
 }
```

When you use this logic, `progress(20, 100, 30)` will give 30 and `progress(100, 20, 30)` will give 90.
The basic logic is: add (or subtract) the difference between your lower value and the current value to your initial value.

Note, this function can always be compressed down to a single line once you know your start and finish values.  While you can use it as code, it's more intended as pseudo-code to help you understand how to make it a single line.  Using this general form, your two cases were:

20 + (current - 20)  // == current, i.e. your original line of code

and

100 - (current - 20) // == 100 - (-(20 - current) == 100 + (20 - current), i.e. the answer I gave.